# CSS: Aligning breadcrumb

Tags: html, css, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to align a breadcrumb with the rest of its body.

```css
BODY {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: tan;
}
/* breadcrumb styles */

#test-breadcrumb ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-table;
  padding-left: 2px;
}
#test-breadcrumb ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 32px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
#test-breadcrumb ul li.test-breadcrumb-active {
  background: #00abe2;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#test-breadcrumb ul li:after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 16px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 16px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
#test-breadcrumb ul li.test-breadcrumb-active:after {
  border-left: 16px solid #00abe2;
}
#test-breadcrumb ul li:before {
  content: "";
  border-top: 16px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 16px solid transparent;
  border-left: 16px solid #efefef;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#test-breadcrumb ul li:first-child {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#test-breadcrumb ul li:first-child:before {
  display: none;
}
.test-breadcrumb-area {
  padding: 32px 0 12px 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.test-navbutton-inactive {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 32px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #666666;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-breadcrumbs">
  <div class="test-breadcrumb-area">
    <div id="test-breadcrumb">
      <div id="test-navbutton-shared" class="test-navbutton-inactive">Shared</div>
      <div id="test-navbutton-personal" class="test-navbutton-inactive">Personal</div>
      <div id="test-navbutton-users" class="test-navbutton-inactive" style="cursor: pointer;">Users</div>
      <ul>
        <li id="test-breadcrumb-user-label" class="test-breadcrumb-active">test user 1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="test-clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lpk8qdd/7/)

I've noticed that removing the `float:left` on line:14 shifts the test user breadcrumb slightly down but that doesn't solve the problem and I expected it to move sideways and not vertically. I've also added `vertical-align: middle` line:16 however it doesn't seem to make much difference.

What should I modify to align the last breadcrumb properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd want to give it the same margin as the rest of the body and vertical align it bottom.

ex:

```
#test-breadcrumb ul {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1Lpk8qdd/9/

### EDIT

A better solution would be to remove the margin and vertical align it top.

ex:

```
#test-breadcrumb ul {
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1Lpk8qdd/11/

Comment: No problem, I updated my answer with a better solution which doesn't involve having to match the same margin as the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the CSS as in Vic's answer, which is perfectly legitimate, but I see it as an issue of overly complex markup and style. You can save yourself a lot of future headaches if you use markup suited for the problem you're trying to solve.

### The Solution

This is a perfect use case for the `inline-block` element, which is intended for things like listing multiple inline elements that need to have block-level properties like padding, background color, etc. Instead of trying to reconcile floated and non-floated elements, make all the items part of an unordered list, and using broader classes to style list items.

I've simplified your HTML & CSS to use classes and simpler markup to achieve the same effect:

```css
body {
    background: tan;
}

.breadcrumb-wrap {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.breadcrumb {
    background: #fff;
    color: #666;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 2em;
    margin: 0 8px 0 0;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.breadcrumb.active {
    background: #00abe2;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 15px 0 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.breadcrumb.active:after {
    content:"";
    border-bottom: 16px solid transparent;
    border-left: 16px solid #00abe2;
    border-top: 16px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    right: -15px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="breadcrumb-wrap">
    <li class="breadcrumb">Shared</li>
    <li class="breadcrumb">Personal</li>
    <li class="breadcrumb">Users</li>
    <li class="breadcrumb active">Test User 1</li>
</ul>
```